# how do I fix bracket matching on Netbeans + Javascript?

Tags: ide, netbeans, brackets

I've been using Netbeans for a while as my PHP editor, I have some pages with javascript and the bracket matching is really bad: (bracket is highlighted in blue but it can't find it's match)
as shown below:
http://i40.tinypic.com/119c8wz.png
http://i43.tinypic.com/pr9r7.png

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with netbeans and many problems they have to fix yet in the area of code formatting.